# share mouse&keyboard between linux and windows using x2x and a xserver

Tags: linux, windows-10, keyboard, mouse, xorg

I want to use my keyboard and mouse attached to a Linux machine to control the windows machine.
  The two machines are in a local network. So theoretically I should be able to use the x2x in linux with an X server in windows to make this work, right?

In Windows side I installed `vcxsrv` and run it. Suppose the address is 192.168.1.17.
  In Linux side I run command

```
DISPLAY=192.168.1.17:0 xclock
```

and a clock will show in windows as expected.
  But if I run

```
x2x -east -to 192.168.1.17:0 -from :0
```

I will get the error message

```
BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
```

every time I move the mouse to the right edge of screen, which is supposed to "move" the cursor to the windows machine.

So what's the error "BadMatch" means here? And how to fix it so I can share the mouse and keyboard?

Comment: did you try [synergy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synergy_(software))?

Comment: @chicks The `x2x` + `vcxsrv` solution is simpler in my situation, they were already installed, no need to pay or compile source code, and I don't worry about the network security.